# How to render a Link in markdownRemark in a Gatsby project

Tags: markdown, gatsby

I'm working on building a markdown wiki in Gatsby.

It's based off of the `gatsby-blog` starter. It parses markdown files in the `/content/wiki/` with markdownRemark to display as html pages.

In a component I could of course write out a simple text link as:

```
<Link to={`/Some_File`}>Some File</Link>
```

But in my markdown files, links are simply written as:

```
[Some File](Some_File)
```

The problem is that when adding text links to the markdown files it causes a page refresh when the link is clicked.

Is there any way to render a router Link within a markdown file?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-catch-links/?=gatsby-plugin-catch-links

Comment: Yep that plugin does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @ksav!

Answer (score 1):

[`gatsby-plugin-catch-links`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-catch-links) seems to be the best way to achieve this *(also confirmed in gatsby discord channel)*.

From the readme:

#### Installation

```sh
npm install gatsby-plugin-catch-links
```

#### Usage

```js
// In your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-catch-links`]
```